# How to search for Items that doesn't contain certain keywords using Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have millions of items in the database. And user can search those items based on the keyword. In the search function, I need to provide a feature that search for NOT that keyword.

For example `Item A` has a field called `msg` and the value is `Sitecore is awesome and great`.
In the search box, user can check the checkbox that indicates to show any item that doesn't contain the keyword. Maybe user key in `is` keyword, so `Item A` will not be displayed or retrieved by ADC.

Edit: Currently I'm using sitecore6.6, thus Search method has been deprecated. I have tried the Not keyword by using Occurrence.MustNot, but it doesn't return any result.

Comment: What are you using for the search - Lucene?

Comment: @herskinduk yupe, lucene search

Answer (score 0):

The Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler is an extension of the Sitecore.Search API and Sitecore.Search API is a wrapper around Lucene.

In Lucene you can user queries with `NOT` or `-` to exclude something like `"Sitecore NOT awesome"` or `"Sitecore -awesome"`.

To exclude something you need at least one include term.

Not sure if it works, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you might have luck by using a `MatchAllDocsQuery` and supplying the keywords in the form of a `Filter`.

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("msg", new StandardAnalyzer());
Query userQuery = queryParser.Parse("Sitecore is awesome and great");
booleanQuery.Add(userQuery, reverseQuery.Checked ? BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT : BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

MatchAllDocsQuery matchAllQuery = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
Filter filter = new QueryFilter(booleanQuery);

using (QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner("myIndex"))
{
    var skinnyItems = queryRunner.RunQuery(matchAllQuery, filter, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to NOT include the keywords associated with the result item set is this:

```
 protected List<Item> getSearchResults(string queryToSearch, string selectedFilter, string notToSearch)
    {
        Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
        var index = SearchManager.GetIndex("siteSearchIndexName");

        using (SortableIndexSearchContext context = new SortableIndexSearchContext(index))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            {
                query.ToLower();
                CombinedQuery cq = new CombinedQuery();
                QueryBase qbKeyword = new FieldQuery("_orderkeywordpair", query);
                QueryBase qbContent = new FieldQuery("_content", query);
                QueryBase qbHtml = new FieldQuery("html", query);

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedFilter) && selectedFilter.ToLower() != "all")
                {
                    QueryBase qbFilter = new FieldQuery("_pagetype", selectedFilter);
                    cq.Add(qbFilter, QueryOccurance.Must);
                }
                cq.Add(qbKeyword, QueryOccurance.Should);
                cq.Add(qbContent, QueryOccurance.Must);
                cq.Add(qbHtml, QueryOccurance.MustNot);

                SearchHits hits = context.Search(cq);
```

Comment: I'm currently using sitecore 6.6, so context.Search is a deprecated method. Is there any other method to do it?